# Reading JS Variable from BHO in IE9

Tags: windows, com, ole, bho, internet-explorer-9

I have an Internet Explorer BHO that can execute a script on the current website and then read variables that have been assigned in that script. Unfortunately, as of IE9 (I tested with the RC), reading the JS variable results in a HRESULT 0x80020006.

The script sets assigns the JS variable as follows:

```
this.<js_var> = <value>
```

where `this` is the current Window object. It is executed using

```
hr = pWindow->execScript( ccom_js, lang, &vEmpty );
```

and the JS variable is read using

```
bool get_js_var( CComPtr<IDispatch> pDisp, LPOLESTR name, VARIANT *dest )
{
  DISPID id;
  HRESULT hr = pDisp->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL, &name, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &id );
  if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
    VariantInit( dest );
    VariantClear( dest );
    DISPPARAMS dp = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    hr = pDisp->Invoke( id, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &dp, dest, NULL, NULL );
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      LOG( _T( "failed to get var contents, hresult = 0x%lx" ), hr );
    }
  } else {
    LOG( _T( "failed to get id of var name, hresult = 0x%lx" ), hr );
  }

  return false;
}
```

where `pDisp` has been retrieved using `document->get_Script( &pDisp );`.

This code works fine in previous versions of IE, on Windows XP, Vista and 7. In IE9 the script executes (I can invoke alerts, etc.), but the variable can not be read. What change in IE9 causes this problem?

Comment: Could be wrong `pDisp` param calling `get_js_var`. Which interface do you QI for `IDispatch`?

Comment: `pDisp` was retrieved using `document->get_Script(&pDisp)`, which gives a dispatch pointer to the scripting engine.

Comment: FYI `0x80020006` maps to `DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME` (defined in `WinError.h`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `IDispatch->GetIDsOfNames()` fails to get a Dispatch ID of the variable in IE9, it turns out that using the result from `get_Script()` as `IDispatchEx` instead of `IDispatch` and calling:

```
HRESULT hr = pDispEx->GetDispID( CComBSTR( name ), fdexNameImplicit, &id );
```

instead of

```
RESULT hr = pDisp->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL, &name, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &id );
```

does result in a valid and usable id to be used with `pDispEx->Invoke()`.

To get an `IDispatchEx` pointer, I used:

```
CComPtr<IDispatchEx> pDispEx;
hr = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatchEx, (void**)&pDispEx);`
```